# Create iterative child of iterative parent node using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to convert my xml into another xml such that all child node of a iterative node are stored inside their respective parent node with a different name

XML Code

```
 <changeSummary id="c0C9B039362994319955773B6B7BAB375">
  <group groupID="Building" caption="Building" path="/session/data/account/building" id="g770EEC10BBA64DA6B6DC22AAAAA0F092">
     <instance dataID="b4BDA8E87A6614C7FAE531A4E84D55EF5" location="1" description="" type="add" id="iDD165B3C64CE4E6EB07871E0AE16415C" />
     <instance dataID="b76AACBF9B7954D6FB6FC15E152E0B8AB" location="1" description="" type="add" id="i43428D1464DB4145816579CFC631C392" />
     <instance dataID="bE42CE90DDDD541D2B07D5A46A73AD733" location="1" description="" type="add" id="iA5DF81FDAD5F4C1F89EE7D0BD67EE931" />
  </group>
  <group groupID="BuildingSelect" caption="BuildingSelect" path="/session/data/system/BuildingSelect" id="g4808DF5C47E94C78BB5E3B3939F7B92F">
     <instance dataID="BDB2C4E57D71447A79E75875373C0B174" location="1" description="" type="modify" id="i1994EBCB062744FAAD02B7F6D96B4A32">
        <change fieldID="BuildingSelectInput.BuildingID" path="BuildingID" fullPath="BuildingID" caption="Building" old="0" new="b4BDA8E87A6614C7FAE531A4E84D55EF5" id="c83BCA4F6848848E29BFDB4E24497C5C0" />
     </instance>
  </group>
  <group groupID="Policy" caption="Policy" path="/session/data/policy" id="g236A029860BC4F66AD540FE9754B4640">
     <instance dataID="p9807CAE99CA241D1AF1EA7054FBBBC88" location="1" description="" type="modify" id="iF63B973BF88A4006A57E71B6B6FF1375">
        <change fieldID="PolicyOutput.Premium" path="Premium" fullPath="Premium" caption="Full-Term Premium" old="50" new="1006" id="c8C2402698C944589B440C26AE16D1FE8" />
     </instance>
  </group>
  <group groupID="Line" caption="Line" path="/session/data/policy/line[Type=&quot;InlandMarineAAIS&quot;]" id="gA15A1CF68FE543D2A969ED86848613AD">
     <instance dataID="lA50B4091426F4174AB3449DECEA1A781" location="1" description="" type="modify" id="iBA1D12BC76EB424EABAFABC60DCF2276">
        <change fieldID="LineOutput.Premium" path="Premium" fullPath="Premium" caption="Premium" old="50" new="1006" id="c28C0B8E46403463C9E876718773CEED1" />
     </instance>
  </group>
  <group groupID="Transit" caption="Transit" path="/session/data/policy/line[Type=&quot;InlandMarineAAIS&quot;]/inlandmarinecoverageforms/coverage[Type=&quot;LineTransit&quot;]" id="g3E2195AA85B54CE98657D62ACCA8E6D9">
     <instance dataID="cBF3394C001A64CD09615BEBF617B746E" location="1" description="" type="modify" id="iD9CF30C38AB54DB483554F2CCB048431">
        <change fieldID="TransitInput.ReportingValueEstimated" path="ReportingValueEstimated" fullPath="ReportingValueEstimated" caption="" old="0" new="13213" id="cE98BF36CBA664B5B8D53E01B25AD00CB" />
        <change fieldID="TransitInput.ReportingDepositPremium" path="ReportingDepositPremium" fullPath="ReportingDepositPremium" caption="Reporting Deposit Premium" old="0" new="234" id="cFE0A32DA97194A5491F86D21E2E1C0DA" />
         </instance>
     <instance dataID="c59C840E208C84EE3AAA22EAFFF350B19" location="1" description="" type="modify" id="iD4E74CE616BF4BFE8FF8FACCAC44C91B">
        <change fieldID="TransitUnderwriting.CatastropheLimit" path="limit[Type=&quot;Catastrophe&quot;]/iValue" fullPath="limit[Type=&quot;Catastrophe&quot;]/iValue" caption="Catastrophe Limit" old="0" new="02424" id="c409AA6D0CF924160B97EAD7EB719E9BD" />
        <change fieldID="TransitInput.TripTransitModification" path="TripTransitModification" fullPath="TripTransitModification" caption="Trip Transit Modification" old="1" new="12424" id="cD4A6EB245CE34EDA9A17C9981163A4D6" />
        </instance>
  </group>
  <group groupID="Risk" caption="Risk" path="/session/data/policy/line[Type=&quot;InlandMarineAAIS&quot;]/risk" id="g68E2B05DA0AA44D38E7BF8512FE82701">
     <instance dataID="r998DC26F558A46A0829200B3A55A7FA6" location="1" description="" type="add" id="i85089A5E8D7E46F097BC7F65DBC71761" />
     <instance dataID="r51353AF95FDD4666A8039ED7A3604608" location="1" description="" type="add" id="i1935D0FEC66E4FD48E374F638BC3DA34" />
  </group>
  <group groupID="CoverageElectronicDataProcessing" caption="CoverageElectronicDataProcessing" path="/session/data/policy/line[Type=&quot;InlandMarineAAIS&quot;]/risk/coverage[Type=&quot;ElectronicDataProcessing&quot;]" id="gEF9BBABE5E2D4634AAB844FFBC265267">
     <instance dataID="c4B9061DFF1BC47FCA863532952EC1037" location="1" description="" type="add" id="i2A9997BC4D2641FC889253E900CEDAF8" />
     <instance dataID="c8D5E555101684F56A326C335FC7614DD" location="1" description="" type="add" id="iAE7314C8CA754A82977428A9F6DDB009" />
  </group>
  <group groupID="Agency" caption="Agency" path="/session/data/agencyDetails" id="g0E6DF1F792F64A03811DA2F8026D443C">
     <instance dataID="aD9E2C7F10CCB4FCCAB7A5EEBC56B8961" location="1" description="" type="delete" id="i048431E9A7F745418779A8FEC53AECEE" />
     <instance dataID="a2577D263222548AE99D6E20C1945A33C" location="1" description="" type="add" id="iC22B7F58DED546F4AC2FC93435AF91D8" />
  </group>
  <group groupID="StatCodeRiskCoverageGroup" caption="StatCodeRiskCoverageGroup" path="/session/data///line[Type=&quot;InlandMarineAAIS&quot;]/risk/coverage[Indicator=1]" id="gA7F2C7C30EE04777AA56FF009112385E">
     <instance dataID="c4B9061DFF1BC47FCA863532952EC1037" location="1" description="" type="add" id="i5253953C118C4959B0D71B83E3F53D5E" />
     <instance dataID="c8D5E555101684F56A326C335FC7614DD" location="1" description="" type="add" id="iBA5AC5441B604E949F18E97C30B92E6E" />
  </group>
  <group groupID="StatCodeLineCoverageGroup" caption="StatCodeLineCoverageGroup" path="/session/data///line[Type=&quot;InlandMarineAAIS&quot;]/coverage[Indicator=1]" id="gB14B74154A5B4B11AD2CA385E291FF24">
     <instance dataID="c21147C01698C4F228CD35AD209CC336D" location="1" description="" type="delete" id="i5FBF405EEEEA41D1A4C59BD2E0A88E96" />
     <instance dataID="cE172687562EB4219BFA50D9B3BA276B8" location="1" description="" type="modify" id="i2C1CD873479B4493A447396C12B573D5">
        <change fieldID="StatCodeLineCoverageGroupInput.StatCodePremium" path="Premium" fullPath="Premium" caption="Premium" old="0" new="10" id="cD967D42BA3A94C23906B1B62D951E4DE" />
     </instance>
  </group>
  <group groupID="StatCodeLineCoverageFormsGroup" caption="StatCodeLineCoverageFormsGroup" path="/session/data///line[Type=&quot;InlandMarineAAIS&quot;]/inlandmarinecoverageforms/coverage" id="g5FBD83AB961342FC9D1BAE55BB08DF90">
     <instance dataID="cBF3394C001A64CD09615BEBF617B746E" location="1" description="" type="modify" id="i593B67183F054A2E85754BE6E2318F28">
        <change fieldID="StatCodeLineCoverageFormsGroupInput.StatCodePremium" path="Premium" fullPath="Premium" caption="Premium" old="0" new="996" id="c541E903134B94A6298F24044E0C76BD0" />
     </instance>
  </group>
```

My current xslt:

```
    <xsl:template match="changeSummary">
  <xsl:element name="CovTransitResponse">
         <xsl:for-each select="//changeSummary/group[@groupID = 'Transit']/instance">                      
              <xsl:copy>
               <xsl:element name="CovGroupType">
                  <xsl:value-of select="@id" />
               </xsl:element>
               <xsl:element name="CovID">
                  <xsl:value-of select="@dataID" />
               </xsl:element>
               <xsl:element name="CovType">
                  <xsl:value-of select="@type" />
               </xsl:element>          
             <xsl:for-each select="//changeSummary/group[@groupID = 'Transit']/instance/change">
            <xsl:copy>
               <xsl:element name="ChangeFieldID">
                  <xsl:value-of select="@fieldID" />
               </xsl:element>
               <xsl:element name="ChangeNewValue">
                  <xsl:value-of select="@new" />
               </xsl:element>
               <xsl:element name="ChangeOldValue">
                  <xsl:value-of select="@old" />
               </xsl:element>
               <xsl:element name="ChangeCaption">
                  <xsl:value-of select="@caption" />
               </xsl:element>
               <xsl:element name="ChangePath">
                  <xsl:value-of select="@path" />
               </xsl:element>
            </xsl:copy>
         </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:copy>
         </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:element>
   </xsl:template>
```

Expected output:

```
 <CovTransitResponse>
  <instance>
    <CovGroupType>iD9CF30C38AB54DB483554F2CCB048431</CovGroupType>
    <CovID>cBF3394C001A64CD09615BEBF617B746E</CovID>
    <CovType>modify</CovType>
    <change>
      <ChangeFieldID>TransitInput.ReportingValueEstimated</ChangeFieldID>
      <ChangeNewValue>13213</ChangeNewValue>
      <ChangeOldValue>0</ChangeOldValue>
      <ChangeCaption></ChangeCaption>
      <ChangePath>ReportingValueEstimated</ChangePath>
    </change>
    <change>
      <ChangeFieldID>TransitInput.ReportingDepositPremium</ChangeFieldID>
      <ChangeNewValue>234</ChangeNewValue>
      <ChangeOldValue>0</ChangeOldValue>
      <ChangeCaption>Reporting Deposit Premium</ChangeCaption>
      <ChangePath>ReportingDepositPremium</ChangePath>
    </change>
    </instance>
  <instance>
    <CovGroupType>iD4E74CE616BF4BFE8FF8FACCAC44C91B</CovGroupType>
    <CovID>c59C840E208C84EE3AAA22EAFFF350B19</CovID>
    <CovType>modify</CovType>
    <change>
      <ChangeFieldID>TransitUnderwriting.CatastropheLimit</ChangeFieldID>
      <ChangeNewValue>02424</ChangeNewValue>
      <ChangeOldValue>0</ChangeOldValue>
      <ChangeCaption>Catastrophe Limit</ChangeCaption>
      <ChangePath>limit[Type="Catastrophe"]/iValue</ChangePath>
    </change>
    <change>
      <ChangeFieldID>TransitInput.TripTransitModification</ChangeFieldID>
      <ChangeNewValue>12424</ChangeNewValue>
      <ChangeOldValue>1</ChangeOldValue>
      <ChangeCaption>Trip Transit Modification</ChangeCaption>
      <ChangePath>TripTransitModification</ChangePath>
    </change>
  </instance>
</CovTransitResponse>
```

Current Output:

```
    <CovTransitResponse>
  <instance>
    <CovGroupType>iD9CF30C38AB54DB483554F2CCB048431</CovGroupType>
    <CovID>cBF3394C001A64CD09615BEBF617B746E</CovID>
    <CovType>modify</CovType>
    <change>
      <ChangeFieldID>TransitInput.ReportingValueEstimated</ChangeFieldID>
      <ChangeNewValue>13213</ChangeNewValue>
      <ChangeOldValue>0</ChangeOldValue>
      <ChangeCaption></ChangeCaption>
      <ChangePath>ReportingValueEstimated</ChangePath>
    </change>
    <change>
      <ChangeFieldID>TransitInput.ReportingDepositPremium</ChangeFieldID>
      <ChangeNewValue>234</ChangeNewValue>
      <ChangeOldValue>0</ChangeOldValue>
      <ChangeCaption>Reporting Deposit Premium</ChangeCaption>
      <ChangePath>ReportingDepositPremium</ChangePath>
    </change>
    <change>
      <ChangeFieldID>TransitUnderwriting.CatastropheLimit</ChangeFieldID>
      <ChangeNewValue>02424</ChangeNewValue>
      <ChangeOldValue>0</ChangeOldValue>
      <ChangeCaption>Catastrophe Limit</ChangeCaption>
      <ChangePath>limit[Type="Catastrophe"]/iValue</ChangePath>
    </change>
    <change>
      <ChangeFieldID>TransitInput.TripTransitModification</ChangeFieldID>
      <ChangeNewValue>12424</ChangeNewValue>
      <ChangeOldValue>1</ChangeOldValue>
      <ChangeCaption>Trip Transit Modification</ChangeCaption>
      <ChangePath>TripTransitModification</ChangePath>
    </change>
  </instance>
  <instance>
    <CovGroupType>iD4E74CE616BF4BFE8FF8FACCAC44C91B</CovGroupType>
    <CovID>c59C840E208C84EE3AAA22EAFFF350B19</CovID>
    <CovType>modify</CovType>
    <change>
      <ChangeFieldID>TransitInput.ReportingValueEstimated</ChangeFieldID>
      <ChangeNewValue>13213</ChangeNewValue>
      <ChangeOldValue>0</ChangeOldValue>
      <ChangeCaption></ChangeCaption>
      <ChangePath>ReportingValueEstimated</ChangePath>
    </change>
    <change>
      <ChangeFieldID>TransitInput.ReportingDepositPremium</ChangeFieldID>
      <ChangeNewValue>234</ChangeNewValue>
      <ChangeOldValue>0</ChangeOldValue>
      <ChangeCaption>Reporting Deposit Premium</ChangeCaption>
      <ChangePath>ReportingDepositPremium</ChangePath>
    </change>
    <change>
      <ChangeFieldID>TransitUnderwriting.CatastropheLimit</ChangeFieldID>
      <ChangeNewValue>02424</ChangeNewValue>
      <ChangeOldValue>0</ChangeOldValue>
      <ChangeCaption>Catastrophe Limit</ChangeCaption>
      <ChangePath>limit[Type="Catastrophe"]/iValue</ChangePath>
    </change>
    <change>
      <ChangeFieldID>TransitInput.TripTransitModification</ChangeFieldID>
      <ChangeNewValue>12424</ChangeNewValue>
      <ChangeOldValue>1</ChangeOldValue>
      <ChangeCaption>Trip Transit Modification</ChangeCaption>
      <ChangePath>TripTransitModification</ChangePath>
    </change>
  </instance>
</CovTransitResponse>
```

I know Expected output is wrong because i am taking select clause in second for each from the root of the xml. Is there any way through which after selection parent node in first for each i am able to use that in second for each selection, so that all the child nodes are inside their respective parent node.

Comment: Try changing the inner `<xsl:for-each select="//changeSummary/group[@groupID = 'Transit']/instance/change">` to `<xsl:for-each select="change">`

Comment: It worked. Also i had tried ./change in the inner before your answer, based on xslt documentation, that it points to current iteration, that also didnt work, is my understanding wrong?

Comment: You might want to take some time to start with an XPath tutorial. As for using `select="change"` or `select="./change"`, that should give the same result.